# JQuery - get first occurence of class travelling upwards anywhere in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several instances of class="reply_count", most embedded inside other elements.  I would like a method to traverse upward anywhere in the DOM to get the first instance of, and get the text value.

In the example below, I tried using prevAll, and getting the first of them.  However, it does not recognize the one that is within a DIV.  That is the one I want to select.  I assume prevAll works for the same level elements, but not nested ones?

My actual code is much more complex, but below is just a simple example of the intent.

What is another method of accessing the first occurrence of a class going upwards regardless of where it is and how it is nested in other elements?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reply_count">15</div>
        <div class="reply_count">10</div>
        <div><span class="reply_count">5</span></div>        
        <div id="click" style="cursor: pointer;">Click Here</div>
        <div class="reply_count">2</div>
        <div class="reply_count">1</div>
        <script>
            $("#click").click(function(){
                value = $(this).prevAll( ".reply_count:first" ).text();
                alert(value);
            });
        </script>  
</body>    
</html>
```

The result is: 10.  I wanted 5.

Comment: Do you want the first-class selected?

Comment: I want the first class='reply_count' going upwards from where you click ('Click Here').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".click").click(function() {
  var c = $(this).parent().find(".reply_count").add(this);
  var t = $(c).index(this);
  var value = $(c).eq((t-1)).text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

**Demo** I've added multiple `<div class="click"` so you can see it working just fine.

```js
$(".click").click(function() {
  var c = $(this).parent().find(".reply_count").add(this);
  var t = $(c).index(this);
  var value = $(c).eq((t-1)).text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reply_count">15</div>
<div class="reply_count">10</div>
<div>4</div>
<div class="click" style="cursor: pointer;">Click Here</div>
<div><span class="reply_count">5</span></div>
<div class="click" style="cursor: pointer;">Click Here</div>
<div><span class="reply_count">1</span></div>
```

Comment: @PatrickEvans very true, thanks for pointing it out, I've added a new solution for it.

Comment: I tried your code, but it failed to select the desired "reply_count" class in my actual DOM arrangement.  In fact, it did not select any of them. Though it worked for the sample DOM I originally posted here, it seems to fail for differing structures (my much more larger and complex one).

Comment: @hder It can be very hard to give you a 100% good snippet if you don't provide your actual code.

Comment: @Casten - yes understood.  Full marks for providing the solution to my sample.  Have found another way to solve my issue, so have accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method. It traverses upwards through the ancestors in the DOM tree and returns the closest parent matching your selector

Comment: Appreciate if you could provide code sample using 'closest'!